# Create "Week_Start" variable in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe that look like the one below.

```
bus_date <- as.Date(c('2017-04-03', '2017-04-04', '2017-04-06', '2017-04-11', '2017-04-13', '2017-04-17'))
sales <- c(100, 110, 120, 200, 300, 100)


daily_sales <- data.frame(bus_date, sales)
```

It is a sales table at the daily level.

I want to create a new variable called "Week_Start" which is the date of the business week.  I have implemented various solutions which allow me to record a week number (1-52) but I need the actual week starting date.

if (bus_date is a Monday)
return(bus_date)
else
return(Monday before bus_date)

So my resulting dataframe would look like:

```
Week_Start <- as.Date(c('2017-04-03', '2017-04-03', '2017-04-03', '2017-04-10', '2017-04-10', '2017-04-17'))
daily_sales2 <- data.frame(bus_date, sales, Week_Start)
```

I know there is probably an easy way to do this, but unsure where to begin.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can do that with `floor_date` from `lubridate`. By default, `floor_date` gives you the preceding Sunday. `+1` gives you Monday.

```
library(lubridate)
daily_sales$Week_Start <- floor_date(daily_sales$bus_date,unit="week")+1
daily_sales
    bus_date sales Week_Start
1 2017-04-03   100 2017-04-03
2 2017-04-04   110 2017-04-03
3 2017-04-06   120 2017-04-03
4 2017-04-11   200 2017-04-10
5 2017-04-13   300 2017-04-10
6 2017-04-17   100 2017-04-17
```

Comment: Another great solution.  I prefer this one because of the flexibility of the arithmetic property.  I could use this to do previous week or next week as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

From `?strptime`

> %w Weekday as decimal number (0–6, Sunday is 0).
>
> %W Week of the year as decimal number (00–53) using Monday as the
>   first day of week (and typically with the first Monday of the year as
>   day 1 of week 1). The UK convention.

```
as.Date(format(daily_sales$bus_date, "%Y-%W-1"), format = "%Y-%W-%w")
#[1] "2017-04-03" "2017-04-03" "2017-04-03" "2017-04-10" "2017-04-10" "2017-04-17"
```